# Validator for custom UIComponent

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm writting my own custom component extended `UIInput` along with custom renderer. I want that my component apply method expression in the `validator` attribute. But validator attribute doesn't rendered to html markup. Thus `writeAttribute("validator", validator, null)` is not valid for this case. How i can do that?

I wrote renderer for `UIInput`.

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily = "javax.faces.Input", rendererType = "text")
public class TextFieldRenderer extends Renderer{
    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException{
        String ClientId= component.getClientId(context);
        String hint= (String) component.getAttributes().get("placeholder");
        String styleClass= (String) component.getAttributes().get("styleClass");
        String value =(String) component.getAttributes().get("value");
        ResponseWriter writer= context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("input", component);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "text", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("name", ClientId, null);
        writer.writeAttribute("placeholder", hint, "hint");
        writer.endElement("input");
    }
}
```

and `text.taglib.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://text.com</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>hintText</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>javax.faces.Input</component-type>
            <renderer-type>text</renderer-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

I write validation method in `LBean.java`

```
 public void validateLoginField(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {
        if (((String) value).length() < 4) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Must contains more then 4 caharacters");
            context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(), msg);
        } else if (((String) value).length() > 25) {
            FacesMessage msg= new FacesMessage("Must contains less then 25 character");
            context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(), msg);
        }
    }
```

Now I write `index.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:lpform="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/lpform"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:text="http://text.com">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <text:hintText id="ht" placeholder="hint" validator="#{LBean.validateLoginField}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="4"/>
            </text:hintText>
            <h:commandButton value="sub"/>
            <h:message for="ht"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I want to validate value of `hintText` with `validator` attribute like it executed on `<h:inputText validator="#{LBean.validateLoginField}"/>`. But neither `<f:validateLenght minimum="4">` nor `validator="#{LBean.validateLoginField}"` doesnt validate my `hintText`.

Comment: Can you provide your entire code? It seems impossible to see the problem with the provided info.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker Updated.